# RecyclerView HORIZONTAL положение элементов

Tags: android

На разных устройствах разное количество элементов влезает в экран. В чем может быть дело ? Проверял на множеств устройствах на 2 эмуляторах и 7 разных тел.
результата всего 2 :[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Использую только эти параметры

```
setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(view.getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
```

Как мне вывести например по 4 или 3 элемента чтобы на всех устройствах выглядело одинаково

Comment: Ну у разных устройств разные размеры, в том числе и в относительных единицах (dp). Так что это нормально что на разных экранах врезает разное количество элементов. Да и какая разница сколько влезает, есть же прокрутка. Если же вам ну очень надо сделать именно по 3 элемента, то выставляйте размер вьюшки элемента в адаптере при создании вьюшки как треть экрана программно.

Comment: @xkor, я просто новичок в андроиде и не совсем понимаю. разве там нету размеров на которые не зависят размер экрана вроде "они должны сами подгонятся под экран и выглядеть одинаково? А много моментов где на одном так на другом так, и ведь неизвестно как будет на 3 которого у меня нету. разница в эстетике

Comment: так они и выглядят одинаково, только одинаково не относительно размеров экрана, а относительно физических величин, сантиметра например. а размеров зависящих от размеров экрана нет и смысла в них нет, не нужны они